# Behaviour of bool_and and bool_or with NULL values

Tags: postgresql, null, boolean, aggregation

I am working with the aggregation functions `bool_or` and `bool_and` to aggregate some records and see whether there is disgreement on a particular column.
According to the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-aggregate.html):

```
bool_and(expression)    true if all input values are true, otherwise false
bool_or(expression)     true if at least one input value is true, otherwise false
```

However this test query:

```sql
SELECT bool_or(val),bool_and(val) FROM UNNEST(array[true,NULL]::bool[]) t(val)
```

Yields `true` for both columns.

I think `bool_and` is excluding `NULL` values. Is there any way to use built-in aggregation functions to make the above query return `true` and `NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it looks like `NULL` inputs are ignored by these aggregates.

This kind of stupidity almost certainly comes straight from the SQL standard (though I'm not about to [pay $200](https://www.iso.org/standard/63555.html) to find out for sure). Other standard aggregates like `sum(var)` work this way, and it seems like they probably just extrapolated from there, without considering the inherent difference between arithmetic and boolean operations when it comes to handling `null` values.

I don't think there's any way to work around it; I believe the only way you can convince these functions to return a `NULL` is by feeding them an empty dataset. (As an aside, whoever insisted that the `sum()` of zero rows should be `NULL` rather than `0` ought to be committed...)

Luckily, Postgres is infinitely extensible, and defining you own aggregates is pretty trivial:

```
CREATE FUNCTION boolean_and(boolean, boolean) RETURNS boolean AS
  'SELECT $1 AND $2'
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE AGGREGATE sensible_bool_and(boolean)
(
  STYPE = boolean,
  INITCOND = true,
  SFUNC = boolean_and,
  -- Optionally, to allow parallelisation:
  COMBINEFUNC = boolean_and, 
  PARALLEL = SAFE
);
```

If you just need this for a one-off query, and don't want to (or don't have the permissions to) add a new aggregate definition to the database, you can put these in your connection-local temp schema by defining and referring to them as `pg_temp.boolean_and()`/`pg_temp.sensible_bool_and()`.
(If you're using a connection pool, you might want to drop them when you're done.)

Note that this is ~10x slower than the built-in `bool_and()` (though not likely to be the bottleneck in many realistic use-cases); SQL `boolean` values are heap-allocated and immutable, so `boolean_and()` needs to allocate a new one for each iteration, while `LANGUAGE C` functions are allowed to update an accumulator in-place. If performance is a concern, and you're willing/able to [build](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-pgxs.html) and deploy your own C module, then (as with most internal functions) you can pretty easily copy-paste the [`bool_and()` implementation](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/7559d8ebfa11d98728e816f6b655582ce41150f3/src/backend/utils/adt/bool.c#L283) and tweak it to suit your needs.

But all of this is kind of overkill unless you have a real need for it. In practice, I would probably go for @Luke's solution instead.

Comment: "*This kind of stupidity almost certainly comes straight from the SQL standard*" - yes it does. But it's not stupid. In fact I think it's quite logical. If `sum()` didn't ignore NULL values, the result of a sum would have to be `null` if only a single null value was present (because `1 + null + 2` yields `null`). Hardly the result you would expect, would you?

Comment: If you want to actually include NULL values, you need to convert them to some default value, e.g. `bool_or(coalesce(the_column, true))` - but that's pretty much the same as `bool_or(the_column)`

Comment: It really boils down to the philosophy behind nullable boolean logic. I would be absolutely okay with the results of `bool_or` and `bool_and` if running `SELECT true AND NULL` did not return `NULL` as it currently does.
Basically if `NULL` is in a collection it is skipped, while if it is specified strictly it introduces uncertainty.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: My apologies, didn't mean to imply that, but I definitely did (now edited). The way `sum()` handles `null` values is fairly sensible, as they don't serve any real purpose in arithmetic; the stupid part is extending this behaviour to boolean aggregates, despite having defined meaningful semantics for `null` values in boolean expressions.

Comment: If all operators returned `null` on `null` input, then having a similarly uniform behaviour for aggregates might make sense, but this smells to me like two different decisions made two different committees. In any case, having `every(var)` return `true` when not every `var` is `true` seems a little absurd. (And the fact that Postgres had to rename these aggregates just to arrive at a parseable grammar probably tells you all you need to know about how well these people tend to think things through...)

Answer (score 4):

For the purpose of what I needed to do, I ended up using two additional columns which you can see in the updated test query:

```sql
SELECT
  bool_or(val),
  bool_and(val),
  bool_or(val IS NULL),
  bool_and(val IS NULL)
FROM UNNEST(array[true,NULL]::bool[]) t(val)
```

This is enough to cover all three values I can have for this column.

**Note that using `COUNT(DISTINCT val)` won't work since `NULL` is not included**

I hope this can help someone!

Comment: Did this work for you ? I see that `bool_and(val IS NULL)` is only `null` if all values are `null`

Comment: Yes, this addresses all possible combination of counting over sets with `NULL` values.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is:

```
SELECT bool_or(val),bool_and(val) FROM UNNEST(array[true,NULL]::bool[]) t(val) 
       having bool_and (val is not null)
```

I hope it will be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just do this to get the desired behavior:

```sql
SELECT
  BOOL_OR(val),
  BOOL_AND(COALESCE(val, FALSE)) 
FROM
  UNNEST(array[TRUE, NULL]::bool[]) t(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following to have a *bool_and* like that returns true, false or null if respectively all values are true, all values are false, one value is null :

```
select
  case when count(case when val IS null then 1 end) > 0 
    then null 
      else bool_and(val) 
        end
from unnest(array[true,null]::bool[]) t(val)
```